# How do I have a workflow wait until a date field is entered or changed in Sharepoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, 2013, designer-workflow

I see examples with "Wait for Change" in an date field (column) for SharePoint Designer 2010, but in those examples the condition is selectable (equal, not equal, etc.) but in Designer 2013 it appears to be hard coded to just "is equal". I need it to run when the date field is first entered or has changed and hopefully doesn't require adding a column in the list. This list already has 20 date fields that would need another 20 more hidden fields. I assume there might be a need for a separate workflow for starting when you add a record and another workflow for when you are modifying that "field".  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

It's odd that your only selection is just "is equal".... The condition should show more choices than that......

[image]

Try this..... (SharePoint 2013 Workflow)

If (your Date Field) is not equal to 1/1/1900)
and ensure both "Start workflow automatically when an item is created" AND "Start workflow automatically when an item is changed" are both selected.

[image]

Comment: The OP was talking about the "wait for change" action, not conditions.

Answer (score 2):

The screen shots above show an "if" action, they asked about the "wait for field change" action. Unfortunately the ability to change this from "equal to" was removed in SPDesigner 2013:

http://blog.fpweb.net/sharepoint-headache-change-in-wait-for-field-change/

Thanks.
SG.